# HPE Dl380 Gen 10 + P822 + SAS Disks + Truenas +HBA Mode

Tags: raid, sas, truenas, hpe

Hi I have a DL380 Gen10 server and an P822 SAS expander laying around which I want to repurpose as a truenas box. I have a bunch of 2TB SAS drives which I want to use for this. I have managed to switch my P822 into HBA mode and when I go into the ACU I can see 8 2TB drives present. However Truenas doesn't see them at all. If I plug SATA drives into the P822 they are detected by Truenas. I have read online issues with HPE Raid cards and HBA mode, requiring you to define raid 0 arrays for each drive. Is this the case for this configuration?

Comment: Certainly that would sort it, just 8 x R0, are they HP disks? HPA array cards are notorious for hating non-HP drives.

Comment: Yes they are all HPE disks. I just woneder if there are any performance implications of having them in R0 array rather than direct HBA access?

Comment: No, shouldn't be